# Resize Image in GridView

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, gridview

I am trying to update an old webapp with an image as a hyperlink in GridView. Since it is old it's not necessarily the way I would like it to be, but I don't want to completely rework it. Here is what I have. If I do this as a hyperlinkfield I can't get the image to render properly. If I do it as an imagefield I can't pass the search value into the url. What can be done to resize the image?

```
<asp:HyperLinkField HeaderText="NIP" 
            DataNavigateUrlFields="DomainUser" 
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http:\\webapp.emersonflowcontrols.net/apps/NIP/search.asp?why=results&terms={0}&column=Equipment%20Description&order=Type" 
            Text="&lt;img src='Graphics\world28.gif' alt='Link to NIP' border='0'/&gt;"
            Target ="_blank " />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [DataTextFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlinkfield.datatextformatstring(v=vs.110).aspx) property and set the width and height explicitly:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField
    HeaderText="NIP" 
    DataNavigateUrlFields="DomainUser" 
    DataNavigateUrlFormatString="http:\\webapp.emersonflowcontrols.net/apps/NIP/search.asp?why=results&terms={0}&column=Equipment%20Description&order=Type" 
    DataTextField="DomainUser"
    DataTextFormatString="<img src='Graphics\world28.gif' alt='Link to NIP' width='50' height='50' border='0'/>"
    Target ="_blank" />
```

Comment: When I do this it does not change the image size. Something about this is treating this as a hyperlink and not an image so it does not want to be resized in the usual way.

Comment: @BrettM Are you sure you are using the DataTextFormatString property and not the Text property as in your example?  Have you inspected the resulting HTML?  This example works perfectly for me.

Comment: @BrettM I just noticed that `DataTextField` also needs to populated in order for `DataTextFormatString` to work, sorry.  Updating example above.

Comment: This has the same issue as my example. The image displayed in GridView but it was stretched and the width and height controls did nothing when I changed their numbers.

Comment: @BrettM Is there CSS that could be interfering?  Can you post a small sample of the rendered HTML for one of the hyperlinks?